# Flickr Integration within android app

Tags: android, flickr, android-developer-api

I have uploaded some pics in "photostream" though the Flickr website.

Now I want to integrate Flickr in my Android app. How can I download those same pics in my device using the Flickr API? I did the "login" part for these but I don't know how to fetch my uploaded images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`flickr.people.getPhotos`](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getPhotos.html) or [`flickr.people.getPublicPhotos`](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getPublicPhotos.html)

> Return photos from the given user's photostream. Only photos visible to the calling user will be returned. This method must be authenticated; to return public photos for a user, use `flickr.people.getPublicPhotos`.

Note that the API docs lists this project https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/ which might make your life easier. In there it is the [`LoadPhotostreamTask`](https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/source/browse/flickrj-android-sample-android/src/com/gmail/yuyang226/flickrj/sample/android/tasks/LoadPhotostreamTask.java).

Comment: It's working properly. I would need to implement AsyncTask for this to execute this method on another thread.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and at this reputation my vote doesn't show publicly.

Comment: You should be able to accept an answer still. You will get 5 rep for that.  Click grey check mark.